# Page not reading CSS files for some ungodly reason

Tags: c#, html, .net

Ok, so I recently had an SEO audit done on my site and per the recommendations I added the Geo.txt, robots.txt, Schema.txt and sitemap.xml files to my root directory (not sure exactly if this is where these files go...) And now for some reason my page displays like there is no CSS file at all.  Could adding one of these files affect that?  Do I need to add the path to my CSS to one of the files?  I will add my header section below.

```
   <head>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-L6BBJ36NQR"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'G-L6BBJ36NQR');
    </script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="contentHead" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Web Development Erie PA Application Custom Software Northwest PA" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico" />

    <!-- CSS here -->
    <link href="" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slicknav.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flaticon.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/progressbar_barfiller.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/gijgo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animated-headline.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/themify-icons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/nice-select.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
    

</head>
```

The page is supposed to look like this:

[Proper site look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bunq.png)

But instead it looks like this:

[Wrong site look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC3YS.png)

Comment: Why are you using webforms in 2022?

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, are all of the CSS files properly loaded?  Do the responses contain the code you expect?  When you debug, focus on one specific element and one specific style rule which is not being applied.  In the DOM explorer, what style rules are being applied to that element?  What style rule are you expecting to see but don't see?  If anything else over-riding that rule?  If it's not there at all, where do you expect it to come from?  Where is it defined?  What is that rule and is it in the response for the CSS file you expect?